# flutter 2.0.1 pub get failed

Tags: flutter, dart

I`ve upgraded to the recent flutter version 2.0.1.

My `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  background_fetch: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.1
  camera: ^0.8.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.0-beta7
  division: ^0.8.8

  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  fixnum: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  flutter_ble_lib: ^2.3.2
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0-nullsafety.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.21.0-nullsafety.0
  freezed_annotation: ^0.14.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8

  freezed: ^0.14.0+1
  get: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.2
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0
  hex: ^0.2.0
  intl: ^0.17.0

  location: ^4.1.1
  logger: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.0
  lottie: ^1.0.1
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.2
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  permission_handler: ^6.0.1+1
  protobuf: ^2.0.0
  protoc_plugin: ^20.0.0
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.26.0
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.2.0-nullsafety.0
  sms_autofill: ^1.3.1
  sprintf: ^6.0.0
  system_settings: ^1.0.1
  timezone: ^0.7.0-nullsafety.0
  uuid: ^3.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.0-nullsafety.1






dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test:
  hive: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.11.5
  effective_dart: ^1.3.1
  json_serializable: ^4.0.2

  flutter_oss_licenses: ^1.0.0







flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

When i run `flutter pub get`

I get an error:

> Because genius_app depends on path_provider 2.0.1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; Because genius_app depends on path_provider 2.0.1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)

And this is not related to the `path_provider`, because if i remove this package, i start to receive same error for other packages

I`ve tried to work with` fvm` - and everything works just fine.
This error is happens only when i use local flutter environment

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale
    en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```